# tkinter file pattern set in a file dialog

Tags: python, tkinter

To get the set of expected files with given extensions in a file dialog, I've seen in several places written patterns as `('label','pattern')`, the pattern being in one string. However the following doesn't work

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
fd.askopenfilenames(
    title='Choose a file',
    filetypes=[('all files', '.*'),
               ('text files', '.txt'),
               ('image files', '.png;.jpg'), # nope,returns *.png;.jpg
               ('image files!', '*.png;*.jpg')]) # neither
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are trying to associate two or more suffixes with a single file type (eg: "image files"), there are a couple of ways to do it.

### declare each suffix separately

You can specify each suffix on a separate line. They will be combined into one item in the dropdown list:

```
filenames = fd.askopenfilenames(
    title="Choose a file",
    filetypes=[('all files', '.*'),
               ('text files', '.txt'),
               ('image files', '.png'),
               ('image files', '.jpg'),
           ])
```

### using a tuple

You can also specify them as a tuple:

```
filenames = fd.askopenfilenames(
    title="Choose a file",
    filetypes=[('all files', '.*'),
               ('text files', '.txt'),
               ('image files', ('.png', '.jpg')),
           ])
```

Answer (score 4):

Use tuple `('.png', '.jpg')`

```
 ('image files', ('.png', '.jpg')),
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import tkinter
options = {}
options['defaultextension'] = '.txt'
options['filetypes'] = [('all files', '.*'), ('text files', '.txt'),('asc files', '.asc')]
options['initialdir'] = '.'
file_open = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r', **options)
```